# if statement to skip foreach but still run code inside

Tags: php

How can I run the code within the `foreach` loop when I only have one bank account, while avoiding duplicate code?

```
<?php 
    if($_GET['bank_id']>0){
        $id = ($_GET['bank_id']);
        $bank_account = BankAccounts::find_by_id($id); 
    }else{
        $bank_accounts = BankAccounts::find_all(); 
    }
?>

    <table class="bordered">
      <tr>
        <th>accounts id</th>    
        <th>accounts name</th>  
        <th>accounts number</th>    
        <th>account</th>    
      </tr>

    <?php 
    if(isset($bank_accounts)){
    foreach($bank_accounts as $bank_account){
        ?>
      <tr>
        <th><?php echo $bank_account -> bank_accounts_id; ?> </th>  
        <th><?php echo $bank_account -> bank_accounts_name; ?> </th>    
        <th><?php echo $bank_account -> bank_accounts_number; ?> </th>  
        <th><?php echo $bank_account -> bank_account; ?> </th>  
      </tr>
    <?php
        } 
        }else{
    ?>
        <tr>
        <th><?php echo $bank_account -> bank_accounts_id; ?> </th>  
        <th><?php echo $bank_account -> bank_accounts_name; ?> </th>    
        <th><?php echo $bank_account -> bank_accounts_number; ?> </th>  
        <th><?php echo $bank_account -> bank_account; ?> </th>  
      </tr>
 <?php  } ?>
    </table>
```

Comment: Don't differentiate between `$bank_account` and `$bank_accounts`; only have `$bank_accounts`, a single bank account is then simply a list of bank accounts with just one item in it. Single case == list of 1 item, not completely separate logic branch.

Comment: Isn't it a bit radical to close and now soon delete this question within a few minutes, without leaving any time to improve it?

Comment: @this.lau_ the question will not be deleted, as there is an upvoted accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have one bank account, add it to an array with one element. That allows you to avoid duplicate code and means 0, 1 or multiple bank accounts are treated in a uniform way:

```
<?php 
  $bank_accounts = array();
  if($_GET['bank_id']>0){
    $id = ($_GET['bank_id']);
    $bank_account = BankAccounts::find_by_id($id); 
    $bank_accounts[] = $bank_account;
  } else {
    $bank_accounts = BankAccounts::find_all(); 
  }
?>

<table class="bordered">
  <tr>
    <th>accounts id</th>    
    <th>accounts name</th>  
    <th>accounts number</th>    
    <th>account</th>    
  </tr>

  <?php foreach($bank_accounts as $bank_account): ?>
    <tr>
      <th><?php echo $bank_account -> bank_accounts_id; ?> </th>  
      <th><?php echo $bank_account -> bank_accounts_name; ?> </th>    
      <th><?php echo $bank_account -> bank_accounts_number; ?> </th>  
      <th><?php echo $bank_account -> bank_account; ?> </th>  
    </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Also consider using `foreach/endforeach` within HTML code as it's more readable.

Comment: Why not simply `$back_accounts = [BankAccounts::find_by_id($id)]`?

Comment: @deceze, in general I prefer to define variables (eg. $bank_accounts) within the scope it's needed to avoid undefined variable issues as the code gets more complex. In this case, it would indeed be equivalent to use your method.

Comment: @this.lau_ thanks it worked i did originally have foreach as you mentioned